# Do not escape variable in awk

Tags: awk

I got a text file a.txt like that:

```
start_date:{start_date};end_date:{end_date}
```

I want to replace {start_date} and {end_date} in shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
START_DATE="2021-06-01"
END_DATE="2021-06-02"
awk '{gsub(/{start_date}/, '$START_DATE'); gsub(/{end_date}/, '$END_DATE');print $0 }' a.txt
```

I want to get something like:

```
start_date:2021-06-01,end_date:2021-06-02
```

But acutally I got:

```
start_date:start_date:2014;end_date:2013
```

It seems that the variable START_DATE and END_DATE was calcuated in script.It try to wrap variable with double quotes but also failed. How to escaped them in awk?

Comment: You are interpolating the shell variables without any quoting whatsoever, so they look to Awk like mathematical expressions instead of strings. Indeed, 2021-6-1 evaluates to 2014.

Comment: Wow!  Just wanted to compliment you @tripleee for an excellent diagnosis of the "math" at play.  To the original poster, look into `shellcheck` as a tool to help catch many issues like this.  It is an eye-opening experience to learn all the potential errors that can happen when working with bash/shell.

Comment: Thanks. The tool is available at http://shellcheck.net/ though of course you can install it locally as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
awk -v sd="$START_DATE" -v ed="$END_DATE" '{gsub("{start_date}", sd); gsub("{end_date}", ed)}1' a.txt
```

where

- `-v sd="$START_DATE" -v ed="$END_DATE"` - passes `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` variables to the `awk` script and initialize `sd` and `ed` variables with these values
- `gsub("{start_date}", sd); gsub("{end_date}", ed)` - replace the placeholder text with these values
- `1` replaces `print` command that is just shorter and does the same.